# How to Convert text file to NPZ file using Python

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

[image]

I have successfully converted an NPZ file to text, after doing some modifications now I want to convert it back to NPZ file using Python.

Comment: This would be easier to answer, if you will give an idea about how the txt file looks like. Using ```numpy.savez()``` might help.

Comment: What have you shown us?  The csv file, the array from `loadtxt` or something else?  It's hard to tell what you've done, and what you do or do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, that you used `numpy.savetxt()`, in order to convert a numpy array to a text file.

You can convert the file to NPZ format using `numpy.savez()`

Another approach, if you want to load the .txt file as an Array is to use `numpy.loadtxt()`, it is recommended to use `reshape` as well to properly define the rows and column of the array.

Comment: I have tired using `numpy.savez()`, but the output of that file is not similar to the original one

Comment: Is the shape of the array different? would it be possible for you to post a frame of the array?

Comment: Please check, i have added the picture

Comment: Can you please clarify whether this is the array you obtained after converting the file using `numpy.savez()` or is it the original NPZ file?

Comment: i got this data by converting NPZ file to text file, i did some modifications in it, and want to convert it back to NPZ.